# attempt to index nil with 'findFirstChild' Error

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local debounce = true
local infinite = 2

local cooldownOption = script:FindFirstChild("EnableCooldown")
local cooldownTime = cooldownOption:FindFirstChild("CooldownTime")

-- COOLDOWN


if debounce == true and cooldownOption == true then
    repeat
    debounce = false
    game.ReplicatedStorage.AttemptConvertCash:FireServer("Convert Cash")
    infinite = infinite + 1
    wait(cooldownTime.Value)    
    until infinite == 1
    
-- WITHOUT COOLDOWN 
    
elseif cooldownOption == false then
    repeat
    game.ReplicatedStorage.AttemptConvertCash:FireServer("Convert Cash")
    infinite = infinite + 1
    until infinite == 1
    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    
elseif cooldownTime == nil or cooldownTime == 0 then error("Cooldown Time is equal \"nil\"")
end
```

Here is my code, i don't know how to fix it, i tried everything. (also im a new dev)
Please help.
Also, if you need more details, ask me.

Thank you if you can help me :D That would be nice :D

Comment: Probably `script:FindFirstChild` returns `nil` (nothing was found).  You should be ready for `cooldownOption == nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, you're missing values. I have added the fix to your code below.

```lua
local debounce = true
local infinite = 2
local cooldownOption = Instance.new("BoolValue")
cooldownOption.Parent = script
cooldownOption.Name = "EnableCooldown"
local cooldownTime = Instance.new("NumberValue")
cooldownTime.Parent = script
cooldownTime.Name = "CooldownTime"


--VALUES


cooldownOption.Value = false
cooldownTime.Value = 0.5


-- COOLDOWN


if debounce == true and cooldownOption == true then
    repeat
        debounce = false
        game.ReplicatedStorage.AttemptConvertCash:FireServer("Convert Cash")
        infinite = infinite + 1
        wait(cooldownTime.Value)    
    until infinite == 1
    -- WITHOUT COOLDOWN 
elseif cooldownOption == false then
    repeat
        game.ReplicatedStorage.AttemptConvertCash:FireServer("Convert Cash")
        infinite = infinite + 1
    until infinite == 1
elseif cooldownTime == nil or cooldownTime == 0 then 
    error("Cooldown Time is equal \"nil\"")
end
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Line 5 Please, also ill try the code (and check if i didnt made an error on the findFirstChild)

Comment: I got a new error: API Services rejected request with error. HTTP 403 (Forbidden). I think i only have to try it in roblox and not roblox studio

Comment: this time, the error is in this line: 17

Comment: oh wait, its in another file, thanks you !